# Unable to delete pictures on Photos App

Tags: macos, photos

I have selected many photos as seen in the screenshot. I have clicked the `delete` button and all i get is an audible "not today" sound. Nothing happens. Why is this [documented] way of deleting not working?

[image]

Documentation: [Delete photos and videos docs on support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/delete-photos-or-recover-deleted-ones-pht3bfab2f96/mac#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Photos%20app%20on,in%20the%20Recently%20Deleted%20album.)

> Delete selected photos and videos in Days view: Press Delete, then click Delete. The selected items are deleted from your library and placed in the Recently Deleted album.

When I put in `delete` in Help: it shows the `delete` option grayed out

[image]

Comment: Are they in  a shared or icloud album?

Comment: @Allan They're in iCloud but i don't know about folders.   If they're in iCloud there still would need to be some way to delete them..

Comment: Log into iCloud and go into Photos.  From there you should be able to delete them. If they are a shared item (from someone else) you won’t be able to delete them.